# Reverse a selection of data from a specific column if value in a cell meets a criteria

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have a form where users enter the name of a project and the type of transaction.

I have written a macro that returns a selection of data from a table based on the name of the project the user entered, and it works perfectly.

Now I need to add in a function that reverses the order of that same list if the user enters a specific transaction type, it reverses the order of the same list of data.

For example, if type A returns:

Bob

Jerry

Andrew

Jeff

Then type B would reverse that order and return:

Jeff

Andrew

Jerry

Bob

The VBA I wrote for the first portion, to return the list based on project name is:

```
Sub finddata()

Dim projectName As String
Dim transactionType As String
Dim finalRow As Integer
Dim i As Integer

Sheets("Template_Test").Range("G10:I38").ClearContents

projectName = Sheets("Template_Test").Range("E10").Value
finalRow = Sheets("Project_Structure").Range("A20000").End(xlUp).Row
transactionType = Sheets("Template_Test").Range("E14").Value

For i = 2 To finalRow
    Sheets("Project_Structure").Activate
    If Cells(i, 1) = projectName Then
        Sheets("Project_Structure").Range(Cells(i, 2), Cells(i, 4)).Copy
    Sheets("Template_Test").Activate
        Sheets("Template_Test").Range("G100").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats
        End If
Next i

Sheets("Template_Test").Range("E10").Select

End Sub
```

I can get the selection to reverse order using the built in vba function strReverse and a specific range, but my data is not a consistent length of cells - sometimes it's 6 names and sometimes it's 15 - and I can't figure out how to get it to adjust the length it needs to reverse without including blank cells underneath the range.

Comment: You haven't shown your strReverse code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a method using the `.Reverse` method of `ArrayList` object

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub ReverseAList()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, arr(), i As Long, aList As Object, lastRow As Long
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set aList = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
    With ws
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'whichever column is required to determine last row. Assumes there are headers in row1
        If lastRow = 2 Then arr(0) = .Range("A2").Value
        arr = .Range("A2:A" & lastRow).Value
        For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
            aList.Add arr(i, 1)
        Next i

        aList.Reverse

        For i = 0 To aList.Count - 1
            arr(i + 1, 1) = aList(i)
        Next

        .Cells(2, 2).Resize(aList.Count, 1) = arr
    End With
End Sub
```

---

**Data and output**

[image: Data and output]

---

Same thing re-writing a sub by [Ryan Wells](https://wellsr.com/vba/2018/excel/reverse-order-of-array-with-vba/) as a function:

```
Public Sub ReverseAList2()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, arr(), i As Long, aList As Object, lastRow As Long
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    With ws
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'whichever column is required to determine last row. Assumes there are headers in row1
        If lastRow = 2 Then arr(0) = .Range("A2").Value
        arr = .Range("A2:A" & lastRow).Value
        .Cells(2, 2).Resize(UBound(arr), 1) = ReverseArray(arr)
    End With
End Sub

Public Function ReverseArray(vArray As Variant) As Variant
    Dim vTemp As Variant, i As Long, iUpper As Long, iMidPt As Long
    iUpper = UBound(vArray, 1)
    iMidPt = (UBound(vArray, 1) - LBound(vArray, 1)) \ 2 + LBound(vArray)
    For i = LBound(vArray) To iMidPt
        vTemp = vArray(iUpper, 1)
        vArray(iUpper, 1) = vArray(i, 1)
        vArray(i, 1) = vTemp
        iUpper = iUpper - 1
    Next i
    ReverseArray = vArray
End Function
```